# Making OS with assembly With nasm using A boot sector Trying to make kernel

Tags: java, python, c++, operating-system

English is not my native language, so there may be grammar mistakes.

So I have written a boot_Sector.asm file and compile it with nasm to a .bin file and I usually run it with qemu and here's my question:

I need to write a kernel to my OS, but the problem is I don't want to learn C/C++ because I don't have time to do that:

1) Can I write the OS kernel with python or java?

(I prefer Java) And I tried it: I Turned a class file (.java) into a .class file with javac then turned .class file into .o file also turned my boot_Sector.bin file into an .o file

2) How can I link them with .ld file ?

I don't know how so I researched it, but I didn't find any answers. I hope Stackoverflow site can help me.

Here's my boot_sector code

```
bits 32
section .text
        align 4
        dd 0x1BADB002           
        dd 0x00                 
        dd - (0x1BADB002 + 0x00) 

global start
extern kmain            
start:
  cli           
  mov esp, stack_space  
  call kmain
  hlt           

section .bss
resb 8192       
stack_space:
```

Comment: hi @gameplayerxd 1) you need an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without it, whatever help you may want, will not be granted.

Comment: You will not be able to write this in Java; at least not with any standard Java tools. A class file requires a JRE to run.

Comment: cant ı just add All java development kit and runtime enviroment to my Os

Comment: Sure. But it still needs the base OS to run on. So I would say writing your own JVM might be a bit too complicated, though far from impossible. Writing the whole base library without an OS underneath is a different thing.

Comment: Microsoft tried to build an experimental OS in C#: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(operating_system). Might be relevant in an overall structure way. Note that this is still very impractical, and that Java is about as far from a suitable systems language as you can get.

Comment: It is possible to build the higher levels of an operating system in languages like Java or Python. But the JRE and Python interpreter still needs a kernel *below* them to be able to function. If you use a primitive version of Java or Python for that, then you need an even lower level below that, and so on until you really *must* write something in a low-level language like C or even assembler.

Comment: If you're willing to eschew standard tools, you might generate native code with [gcj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java) - but such an approach has limitations.

Comment: OK I get it what about linker files ( .ld ) what do I need to use them

Comment: sorry because I frogot to write I am using Wİndows 7 Professional and 64 bit computer